# What is the significance of the boy crossing the road in the opening scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, ghostland

In *Ghostland*, AKA *Incident in a Ghostland*, the opening scene is of a boy (identified in the credits as 'Amish Boy') crossing a road and stopping in the middle of the road just after the Keller family's car passed by. Vera then looks at the boy.

[image][image]
[image][image]

I thought that the boy escaped from the candy truck home intruders, but I didn't notice any reference to the boy again later.

What is the significance of the boy's appearance in the film?